# Why onSaveInstanceState is calling after onPause

Tags: android, android-activity

In my Android app `onSaveInstanceState()` is always being called when app goes in the background. My understanding was that `onSaveInstanceState()` will be called when OS kills the app. Taking this into account I designed some logic. But, during implementation I noticed this strange behaviour.

Is there a way to differentiate `onSaveInstanceState()` that is being called after OS kills the app, and when it's being called on normal pause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation:

> This method is called before an activity *may* be killed so that when it comes back some time in the future it can restore its state.

In other words, the method is not called immediately before the activity is killed by the OS. It is called when the activity goes into the background and there is a chance that it might later be restored. Saving the state immediately before the activity goes into the background gives the system more flexibility in how it kills applications... once it makes the decision that an application is killed, it can do so immediately (it doesn't have to worry about calling the application's `onSaveInstanceState()` method before it can do so).

Comment: Theory seems fine. But in practical `onSaveInstanceState()` is being called on every pause.

Comment: Exactly, that is why I am trying to say in my answer. :) It is not called immediately before the system actually kills the app. `onSaveInstanceState()` is called immediately when the app goes into the background in case the system kills the app at a later time.

Comment: So in `onSaveInstanceState()` we don't know if its is normal pause or app being killed by OS?

Comment: Correct. After `onSaveInstanceState()` is called, it is possible that the application process will never actually get killed by the OS and is simply resumed again later on. You can think of it more like a preemptive measure, "just in case".

Answer (score 0):

Check the doc: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)

> There are no guarantees about whether it will occur before or after onPause()

Answer (score 0):

onSavedInstanceState() is called before the activity is paused (it isn't visible). If the activity is destroyed on purpose(Ex: the user pressed backspace) onSavedInstanceState() isn't called. The main role of onSavedInstanceState() is to preserve the view.

Short answer: no, you can't.

For more information please read: [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#SavingActivityState) . It's available for fragment too.

Comment: I don't think that is correct, I believe onSavedInstanceState is called AFTER the onPause, not before.